# Não alinha valor zerado no cristal report c#

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Tenho um relatório feito em Crystal Report C# no VS2015.
Nos campos que são decimal quando o valor está zerado o relatório sai com um espaço em branco depois das casas decimais.

Quando não é zero: `|   100,00|`
Quando é zero: `|    0,00 |`

Fica um espaço em branco, quando deveria ficar alinhado à direita.

Acho que isso é algo do gerenciador de relatório. Já tentei resolver de várias formas diferentes.

Comment: Você pode criar uma fórmula, algo como "totext(valor,"00000,00")". Seria algo meio "grosseiro", mas resolveria.

Comment: Fiz o teste, até funciona so que quando insiro a formula eu 'perco' a aba de formatação numérica, aí teria que fazer a formatação no texto. O recurso de arredondamento e bem importante neste caso.

Comment: Que fonte você está utilizando e qual máscara numérica?

Comment: Fonte: Courier New, a formatação eu utilizo na aba Numero em Estilo Personalizado, marquei 'Mostrar Valores Iguais a Zero como: 0,00. Já tentei 'Utilizar formato de contabilidade'.

Comment: Mas você consegue estilizar o resultado da fórmula sem problema nenhum. Não entendo como pôde perder.

Comment: Na aba 'Comum' , coloquei a formula em 'Sequencia de Caracteres', após colocar a formula a aba Número some.